# How can i translate the Django-helpdesk to pt-BR

Tags: django, translation

Is there a way to easily translate the django-helpdesk app to pt-BR?

I noticed a locale file with pt-BR but i don´t know what i should do to translate everything all at once, and i can't find anything specific about it in the oficial docs

Comment: You run `makemessages` on the app, and fill in the `.po` file: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemessages